# Nuget restore fails (NU1201) for .NET Standard referencing .NET Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-standard

I've been googling around a while, but failed to find a proper answer.

My project contains two libraries:

LibA - .NET standard 2.0

LibB - .NET Framework 4.7, which contains some nuget package

I'm referencing (via Project ref) LibB from LibA (i.e. my goal is to use LibB from LibA).
Everything works well if LibB uses packages.config file, but nuget restore fails once I turn to package references in LibB csproj. It gives NU1201, saying that

```
Project LibB is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project LibB supports: net47 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7)
```

Is there any known workaround or this is a VS bug or it just works as designed (I've heard packages.config way skips compatibility check during restore).

Comment: The error message suggests that LibA is referencing LibB which is not supported. A .NET Standard 2.0 project cannot reference a .NET Framework project. A .NET Standard 2.0 project can reference a NuGet package that only supports .NET Framework, or a library assembly (not a project) due to a compatibility mode.

Comment: Also it seems that it should be possible for a .NET Standard 2.0 project to reference a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project but no version higher than 4.6.1 - https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1755

Comment: @MattWard Why you say I cannot reference this way? It's allowed and supported https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg6nR7hS2lI&feature=youtu.be&t=173

Changing target from 4.7 to 4.6.1 (and also to earlier versions) gives no difference. It's only a matter of packages.config vs packages references

Comment: @MattWard So you say I should never reference Framework library via project reference? Why it's allowed by IDE then and what the difference is? As long as I use packages.config my project runs perfectly fine.

Comment: I get the same behaviour as you with Visual Studio 2017. I would file this on github.com/nuget/home/issues and see what the NuGet team say. At the same time if you have a .NET Standard 2.0 project on its own it can install a NuGet package which targets .NET Framework only, you do get a warning about this.

Comment: you can only reference liba from libb (.net standard from .net 4.7)

Comment: @MattWard Yes, but it's only a warning. Completely justified for that case. But for my case I cannot build. Will post issue on github then. Thanks!

Comment: @magicandre1981 no longer true since standard 2.0. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg6nR7hS2lI&feature=youtu.be&t=173

Comment: this is a compatibility shim for old nuget packges. you create new libs, so do it now right. put all platform independent code in .net standard lib and reference this lib in .net framework libs which contains addition Windows only code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nuget restore fails (NU1201) for .NET Standard referencing .NET Framework

Yes, it just works as designed. There is an issue for NuGet restore when you using new  SDK-based project type or PackageReference in the .net framework.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5461

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1755

When we use `packages.config` projects or non-SDK based project type, NuGet do not check compatibility during restore.

So, to resolve this issue, make sure the referenced project is an old style csproj or use `packages.config`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, not sure if "works as designed" fits best to what happens :) But I see there will be no change of this behavior in nearest feature. Thanks